# Task Scheduler randomly not running scripts, reports them as complete

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows server 2008 r2 virtual machine that is set up to run various tasks at night, it reads from a database creating CSVs and copies files to and from locations on other disks. All tasks are set to run while I am not logged in and with full permission. The tasks all run   batch files which in turn run scripts.

What's happening is that most of the time the task report as completed when i check them in the morning but the time it took for completion is 0 seconds (the task did not run basically) no errors are logged and when i right click and run a selected task it executes just fine. This behavior is further complicated by the fact that some tasks will sometimes run just fine as scheduled.

The scripts and batch files work perfectly when I manually run them through task manager the only time they fail (and they dont always fail) is when they are automated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Google to see if 2008 has known issues for task scheduler.  Otherwise it's permissions and scheduler settings or your batch files might have 'gotcha's in there.

Comment: See the batch files are able to run just fine every once in a while and they run fine when I use the run action in task scheduler. Permissions may be something I should look into a little more. Is there a chance they could be failing because they conflict with windows scheduled tasks?

Comment: Well for example the system account has no access to network paths.  Are they running under your account and credentials?

Comment: No they are running in on an elevated account with full permissions with access to networked drives my only other thought is that there are are intermittent issues with the drives it is trying to connect too but would that not return an error to the scheduler?

Comment: No. Any error-checking has to be done in your batch file.

Comment: That would make sense, I will go and see if I cant get ahold of the batch file logs/make sure they are logging things properly.